# Explanation left in a .tex file

Tags: templates, awesome-cv

I'm trying to create my CV in using Awesome_CV.zip (template) from www.sharelatex.com. I tried to compile `resume.tex`, but they ask me to do many things I don't understand.

[image]

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% Awesome CV LaTeX Template
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV
%
% Author:
% Claud D. Park <posquit0.bj@gmail.com>
% http://www.posquit0.com
%
% Template license:
% CC BY-SA 4.0 (https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)
%


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     Configuration
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Themes: Awesome-CV
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{awesome-cv}

%%% Override a directory location for fonts(default: 'fonts/')
\fontdir[fonts/]

%%% Configure a directory location for sections
\newcommand*{\sectiondir}{resume/}

%%% Override color
% Awesome Colors: awesome-emerald, awesome-skyblue, awesome-red, awesome-pink, awesome-orange
%                 awesome-nephritis, awesome-concrete, awesome-darknight
%% Color for highlight
% Define your custom color if you don't like awesome colors
\colorlet{awesome}{awesome-red}
%\definecolor{awesome}{HTML}{CA63A8}
%% Colors for text
%\definecolor{darktext}{HTML}{414141}
%\definecolor{text}{HTML}{414141}
%\definecolor{graytext}{HTML}{414141}
%\definecolor{lighttext}{HTML}{414141}

%%% Override a separator for social informations in header(default: ' | ')
%\headersocialsep[\quad\textbar\quad]


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     3rd party packages
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Needed to divide into several files
\usepackage{import}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     Personal Data
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Essentials
\name{Claud D.}{Park}
\address{246-1002, Gwangmyeongmayrouge Apt. 86, Cheongna lime-ro, Seo-gu, Incheon-si, 22738, Rep. of KOREA}
\mobile{(+82) 10-9030-1843} 
%%% Social
\email{posquit0.bj@gmail.com}
\homepage{www.posquit0.com}
\github{posquit0}
\linkedin{posquit0}
%%% Optionals
\position{Software Engineer{\enskip\cdotp\enskip}Security Expert}
\quote{``Make the change that you want to see in the world."}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     Content
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Make a footer for CV with three arguments(<left>, <center>, <right>)
\makecvfooter
  {\today}
  {Claud D. Park~~~·~~~Résumé}
  {\thepage}

\begin{document}
%%% Make a header for CV with personal data
\makecvheader

%%% Import contents
\import{\sectiondir}{education.tex}
\import{\sectiondir}{experience.tex}
\import{\sectiondir}{extracurricular.tex}
\import{\sectiondir}{honors.tex}
\import{\sectiondir}{presentation.tex}
\import{\sectiondir}{writing.tex}
\import{\sectiondir}{committees.tex}

\end{document}
```

I need explanation please for the following things  and how to do it:

1. "Override a directory location for fonts(default: 'fonts/')"
2. "Configure a directory location for sections"
3. "Override color"
4. "Override a separator for social informations in header(default: ' | ') %\headersocialsep[\quad\textbar\quad] "
5. "Import contents"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1 and 2: folders should be in zip, no need to change. 3: any color you like. 4: have a look at output. 5. The files in sectiondir. Should be provided.  This should compilr fine without changing anything.

Comment: @RunarTrollet I need a little bit more detail.

Comment: Those are explanations what the commands do, not instructions for you. Just unzip the template and start working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
%%% Override a directory location for fonts(default: 'fonts/')
\fontdir[fonts/]
```

These lines say that you can choose a different place for the fonts, if you like, by writing the directory name between the square brackets. The default is `fonts/`, simply because this is currently written there. You don't have to do anything, since your fonts are in the subdirectory `fonts`.

```
%%% Configure a directory location for sections
\newcommand*{\sectiondir}{resume/}
```

These lines say that you can choose a different place for the files containing the sections, if you like, by writing the directory name between the braces. Currently `resume/` is written there. Since you have put the section files into a subdirectory of this name, you don't have to do anything.

```
% Define your custom color if you don't like awesome colors
\colorlet{awesome}{awesome-red}
%\definecolor{awesome}{HTML}{CA63A8}
```

These lines set `awesome` (which determines the color of some elements of the document) to be the color `awesome-red`. The line below it is commented out (=not active) because of the leading `%` sign. It gives an example for an alternate definition. Don't change any colors now. Later, if you don't like some coloring in the document, return to these lines and modify the colors.

```
%%% Override a separator for social informations in header(default: ' | ')
%\headersocialsep[\quad\textbar\quad]
```

The headline will contain a vertical bar to separate two parts. Don't modify it now. If you don't like it later on, return to this place and modify it.

```
%%% Import contents
```

This is just a comment explaning what is happening in the lines below: The contents of the files in subdirectory `resume` (this name is stored in `\sectiondir`) is included in the document. You just have to fill your data into the files in the subdirectory `resume`. Nothing to do here.

---

What you have to do is to write your personal information into the files in the subdirectory `resume`. Then compile `resume.tex` in the main directory. If you get any errors, it is not because of the lines that you are worried about. If you can't help yourself, post a new question here, including the error message as well as the LaTeX source code.